# Oscillate value based on input

Tags: math

Math is not my strong suit; hope to find some help for this pretty basic question. I have a function taking an input value based on a modulus operation. So the input goes from 0-60, then repeats. I want the function to return an value that oscillates within a range. For example, it would return values in the range 0-60, then return values in the range 60-0, then repeat.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Edit** Here is what my function to look like:

```
int convert(int input) {
    // input = 0...1...2... 60...0...1...
    // return= 0...1...2... 60...59...58...
}
```

Comment: Do you want a triangle wave or sine wave?

Comment: I think this explains the math pretty well, http://stackoverflow.com/a/7210726/261114

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand what you want, the simplest answer would be to return `input * 2` if input is less than or equal to 30 and `120 - input * 2` if the input is greater. This will give you a triangular output for a linearly-increasing input.